# Unity5.2.2 で appC cloud の SDK の組み込みに失敗

Tags: android, unity3d

push通知を導入したく SDK をインポートしてビルドしたところ、下記のエラーがでます。

それぞれ調べているのですが、対処法が分からなかったり、試してみてもうまくいかなかったりで、解決できていません。
appC cloud のサポートに問い合わせても返事なしで困ってます。

何かご存知の方いたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

1. ビルドエラー

   Found plugins with same names and architectures, assets/plugins/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar (ARMv7) and assets/plugins/android/android-support-v4.jar (ARMv7). Assign different architectures or delete the duplicate.
2. ビルドエラー

下記のエラーが大量にでます。
(よくネットでひっかかる対処方法ですが、android-sdk 内の 「google-play-services_lib/」のコピーのやり直しなども実施しましたが、ダメでした)

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
/Users/xxx/work/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt package --auto-add-overlay
    -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml
    -S "res"
    -I "/Users/xxx/work/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-22/android.jar"
    -F bin/resources.ap_
    --extra-packages com.google.unity:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms:com.zzz.yyy:com.unity3d.ads.android
    -S "/Users/xxx/work/Apps/yyyyyy/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/google-play-services_lib/res"
    -S "/Users/xxx/work/Apps/yyyyyy/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unity-android-resources/res"
    -S "/Users/xxx/work/Apps/yyyyyy/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads-release/res"
```

Answer (score 1):

1のビルドエラーについては
assets/plugin/android以下に複数のandroid-support-v4.jarがあるためだと思われます。
google-play-services_lib/libs等をご確認し、重複したandroid-support-v4.jarを削除してください。

2のビルドエラーについては
/resフォルダ、またはAndroidManifest.xmlのマージに失敗しているように見えます。
問題となっている箇所を修正するか、もしくは複数のAndroidManifest.xmlを手動でまとめる（assets/plugin/android/AndroidManifest.xmlに）ことで、解決するかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

＞1のビルドエラーについては
assets/plugin/android以下に複数のandroid-support-v4.jarがあるためだと思われます。
google-play-services_lib/libs等をご確認し、重複したandroid-support-v4.jarを削除してください。

google-play-services_lib/libs 以下にもう一つあります。
こちらは、それぞれ path が違うのですが問題になるのでしょうか？
むしろ削除するとどちらかを見ている参照元が include できなくなるのではないでしょうか？
正確には、削除してシンボリックリンクを貼って対応するということを意味します？

＞2のビルドエラーについては
んー、調査は続けているのですが、まだ原因が掴めてないです。

他のプラグインのようにプラグインディレクトリ内にAndroidManifest.xml を含んで、自然とUnity がマージしてくれるようにしてほしいですね・・・。

いままで組み込んだプラグインは、そういった簡単に組み込める設計だったので、
今回は、assets/plugin/android/AndroidManifest.xml を作るはめになり、苦戦中です。。。

Comment: Unityではビルド時に、Plugins/Andorid以下のres,libs,等をまとめて、１つのAndroidProjectとして出力するので、１つのAndroidProjectに複数のandroid-support-v4.jarが存在することが問題となります。

Comment: そういうことなのですね。理解しました。
プロジェクトに一つあればよいというものなので、どちらを消しても良さそうですね。

＞CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. 
こちらは、まだ消えないですね。
appC clound へ問い合わせをしたところ、「Androidプロジェクトを出力して、それにSDKを追加してください」という回答を頂いたので、
【Unity上では、 他のプラグインを入れている場合に、appC clound のSDK 組み込みが無理】そうです。

同じような問題で困っている皆様への有益な情報になれば幸いです。